# Prove that the dot product of two timelike vectors cannot be $0$

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification, inner-products

I am trying to prove that the dot product of two timelike vectors **cannot** be $0$.

The timelike vectors defined as,

$$g(\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_1}) = \vec{v_1} \cdot \vec{v_1} <0$$
$$g(\vec{v_2}, \vec{v_2}) = \vec{v_2} \cdot \vec{v_2} <0$$

And the ortogonality is,

$$g(\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}) = \vec{v_1} \cdot \vec{v_2} = 0$$

where $g(\vec{e}_{\mu}, \vec{e}_{\nu})=g_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu} = diag(-1,1,1,1)$

So I tried something like,

$\vec{v_1} \cdot \vec{v_1} = -(v_1^0)^2 + (v_1^1)^2 + (v_1^2)^2 + (v_1^3)^2 < 0$
So 
$$(v_1^0)^2 > (v_1^1)^2 + (v_1^2)^2 + (v_1^3)^2 = V_1^2 ~~(1)$$
Similarly
$$(v_2^0)^2 > (v_2^1)^2 + (v_2^2)^2 + (v_2^3)^2 = V_2^2 ~~(2)$$ 
And

$\vec{v_1} \cdot \vec{v_2} = -(v_1^0v_2^0) + (v_1^1v_2^1) + (v_1^2v_2^2)+ (v_1^3v_2^3)$

and $L =(v_1^1v_2^1) + (v_1^2v_2^2)+ (v_1^3v_2^3)$

Then I multiplied (1) and (2) to get

$$(v_1^0)^2(v_2^0)^2 > V_1^2  V_2^2$$ I am not sure but then I said,

$$(v_1^0)(v_2^0) > V_1  V_2 > L$$ so $\vec{v_1} \cdot \vec{v_2} <0$.

Is this can be considered as a valid proof. Or is there a more elegant one

Comment: Why is $V_1V_2 > L$?

Comment: From $(v_1^0)^2(v_2^0)^2 > V_1 ^2 V_2^2$ it does not follow that $(v_1^0)(v_2^0) > V_1  V_2$  We know that the right-hand side of the second inequality is positive, and the left-hand side might be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started out okay.
$$\begin{align}
(v_1^0)^2 &> (v_1^1)^2 + (v_1^2)^2 + (v_1^3)^2=||\vec{w_1}||^2\tag1\\
(v_2^0)^2 &> (v_2^1)^2 + (v_2^2)^2 + (v_2^3)^2=||\vec{w_2}||^2\tag2 
\end{align}$$ 
where $\vec{w_i} = v_i^1\mathbf{i}+v_i^2\mathbf{j}+v_i^3\mathbf{k},\ i=1,2$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3.$

Suppose by way of contradiction that $v_i\cdot v_2=0$, that is 
$$v_1^0v_2^0=v_1^1v_2^1+v_1^2v_2^2+v_1^3v_2^3=\vec{w_1}\cdot \vec{w_2}\tag3$$

Multiplying $(1)$ by $(2)$ gives $$(v_1^0)^2(v_2^0)^2>||\vec{w_1}||^2||\vec{w_2}||^2\tag4$$

Squaring both sides of $(3)$ gives
$$(v_1^0)^2(v_2^0)^2=(\vec{w_1}\cdot\vec{w_2})^2\tag5$$

Now, $(4)$ and $(5)$ together contradict the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality).